# I get an error when I enter new input into the middle layer with keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to know how to obtain the output when the new input is input from the middle layer for the model that has been learned.

```py
def encoder(input_):
    d1 = Dense(3, activation='relu', name='encoder_input')(input_)
    d2 = Dense(2, name='encoder_output')(d1)
    return d2

def decoder(input_):
    d1 = Dense(3, activation='relu', name='decoder_input')(input_)
    d2 = Dense(2, name='decoder_output')(d1)
    return d2

# input
input = Input(shape=(2,))

# output
output = decoder(encoder(input))

# model
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model_hist = model.fit(x_train, x_test,
                        epochs=n_epoch,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        verbose=verbose,
                        shuffle=True)

#error:Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor 
tmp_model = Model(input=model.get_layer('decoder_input').input, output=model.get_layer('decoder_output').output)
output = tmp_model.predict(data)
```

Comment: Please also share the error that you get. It would help us to better adress your problem.

Comment: thank you!
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) at layer "input". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Answer (score 0):

I could find two mistakes in yur code:

1. In the encoder in `d2`you forgot `name=` before `'encoder_output'`
2. You forgot the "s" in the line

```
# model
model = Model(input=input, output=output)
```

it should be:

```
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

Else it works for me.
Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you.
But, Fixing this will not be a fundamental solution.
I want to know how to obtain the output when the new input is input from the middle layer for the model that has been learned.
Thank you for your help.